# How do you calculate the deposited energy?

Tags: particle-physics

How do you calculate the deposited energy in a given the distance travelled? Is it simply the stopping power times the distance?

Comment: Recall that stopping power is a function of energy, which complicates life...

Comment: @JonCuster that is my doubt how do I handle it?

Comment: In the first step $dx$ the particle loses $\Delta E(E_0)$. The next step $dx$ the particle loses $\Delta E(E_0-\Delta E)$, and so forth...

Comment: @JonCuster therefore there is no closed  formula, only numeric calculation?

Comment: If you have the energy loss as a function of energy as a function you could integrate over that. It depends on whether you are in a 'convenient' regime of energy loss. Once you get into mixed electronic/nuclear stopping it gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping power is defined as energy loss per unit length of the energetic particle while traveling in a medium.  The stopping power depends on the kinetic energy $S(E)$, the type of particle and the medium.  In practice you need to perform a numerical integration of the form $\int S(E)dx$ to compute the average deposited energy, as the kinetic energy $E$ reduces along the particle's path.

This is not difficult. There are good and publicly available data.

NIST publishes ESTAR, PSTAR and ASTAR for the stopping power of a wide range of materials for electrons, protons and alpha particles; cf https://www.nist.gov/pml/stopping-power-range-tables-electrons-protons-and-helium-ions

The Particle Data Group publishes summary graphs for the stopping power of high-energy particles; cf http://pdg.lbl.gov/, http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf